# PagerAdapter грузит все картинки сразу

Tags: android, gridview

Во время написания галереи для приложения, наткнулся на реализацию GridView + PageAdapter - полноразмерные фотографии нужно было перелистывать пальцем.

Всё работает, но!

Можно как-нибудь заставить работать PageAdapter так, чтобы подгружать в одно время лишь ту фотографию, которую я хочу посмотреть, а не грузить их все по очереди через universal imageloader?
Ведь это трафик... грузить сразу все 100 фотографий для просмотра, скажем 49-ой и ждать пока загрузятся остальные 48....

Либо надо реализовывать подобное через другие инструменты?

**Переделал под пример ниже.**

Теперь стало:

1) при выборе первой картинки из галереи, она не показывается (видимо не срабатывает `public void onPageSelected(int p1)`).

Увидеть её можно лишь после перелистывания на вторую, а затем снова на первую...

2) если выбрать любую картинку кроме первой, то:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null
```

*на строчку*

```
imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView);
```

3) **решено!** если перевернуть экран (картинка альбомной ориентации), то черный экран без ошибок в логкэт и уже нельзя перелистывать фрагменты...

**решение**
В манифесте, для данной активити запрещаем её пересоздание:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

**КОД ПОЛНОСТЬЮ (на всякий случай, если возникнут вопросы по нему)**

**ImagePagerA.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagePagerA extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public ImagePagerA(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < Zakazchik_full.imagesArray.length; i++){
        fragments.add(new ImageShowFragment());
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragments.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

}
```

**ImageViewPager.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ImageViewPager extends FragmentActivity {

int page;
ViewPager mViewPager;
ImagePagerA mPagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    this.page = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerA(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int p1, float p2, int p3) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int p1) {
            page = p1;
            ImageShowFragment fragment = (ImageShowFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(page);
            fragment.showImage(Zakazchik_full.imagesArray[page]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int p1) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

    });

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
}
}
```

**ImageShowFragment.java**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

public class ImageShowFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView imageView;
FrameLayout fl_loading_gallery;
RelativeLayout full_screen_gallery_layout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    return imageView;
}

public void showImage(String url) {

    fl_loading_gallery = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fl_loading_gallery_new);
    full_screen_gallery_layout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.full_screen_gallery_layout_new);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            full_screen_gallery_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fl_loading_gallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            fl_loading_gallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            full_screen_gallery_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            fl_loading_gallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            full_screen_gallery_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю в чем проблема - если у вас отображается одна активная фотография так и грузите ее, если одновременно много - грузите все по очереди, или приведите пример кода как вы загружаете фотки.

Comment: Переписал под Fragment (ответ ниже), но при этом возникло две проблемы, которые я указал в вопросе.

Comment: 1. Код который мы написали для OnPageChangeListener, вызывайте для текущего фрагмента, и передайте ему page, лучше его вынести в отдельный метод, дабы не повторятся. 2. Рас уж все уже переписано, можно и обойтись без onPageChangeListener )) ViewPager по умолчанию хранит только левый, средний и правый фрагменты, больше можно указать используя viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit();

Comment: Предложенный Вами вариант так же не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Код с использованием Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){

        mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int p1, float p2, int p3)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int p1)
                {
                    ImageShowFragment fragment = (ImageShowFragment)mPagerAdapter.getItem(p1);
                    fragment.showImage(GridViewActivity.imagesArray[p1]);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int p1)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                }
            });
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);

    }
}

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for(int i = 0; i < GridViewActivity.imagesArray.length; i++){
            fragments.add(new ImageShowFragment());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

}

public class ImageShowFragment extends Fragment
{

    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        //тут ваш код настройки виджета
        return imageView;
    }

    public void showImage(String url){
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView);

    }

}
```

Comment: Дописал пример с использованием FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, отредактированный вопрос выше (по пункту 3 - решение найдено, 1 и 2 - под вопросом)